Laravel Reverb Client Side Error Connection is unauthorized
I'm encountering an issue while creating a chat app using Laravel 11 and ReactJS. Here's the setup:
Laravel 11 for the backend APIs.
ReactJS for the frontend, which is a separate application.
I'm using Laravel Reverb for broadcasting.
When attempting to connect to the WebSocket, I receive a "Connection is unauthorized" error. Here's the relevant code snippet where I initialize Echo:
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'reverb',
  wsHost: 'localhost',
  key: 'key',
  wsPort: 8080,
  wssPort: 8080,
  forceTLS: false,
  authEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/broadcasting/auth',
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  },
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

However, to authorize the connection, I need a response in this format:
{
  "auth": "reverbAppkey:Token"
}

I have the Reverb App key, but I'm unsure how to generate the token needed for authorization. I've attempted to use a bearer token, but it doesn't seem to work.
Here's a sample response with the expected format:
{
  "auth": "yn0yitpyoptuusssaasadsqiyjrhm:3693e882d4b886d8dadadsasdd70b4d7484e1a80247ea9cafeb4c13b2b44debc87febeef2"
}

Regarding the server-side setup, my channels.php file contains the following:
Broadcast::channel("channel_for_everyone", function ($user) {
  return true;
});

Note: I have tested the broadcasting on laravel application and it works fine but not when try to use in reactjs

@shadyhill : thank , i follow your code and successfully
however i need to edit again it to work
 // channel name will be something like private-room-231 where 231 is accountId
    $socketId = $request->input('socket_id');
    $channelName = $request->input('channel_name');


    // this generates the required format for the response
    $stringToAuth = $socketId . ':' . $channelName;
    $hashed = hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToAuth, env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'));

    return new JsonResponse(['auth' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY') . ':' . $hashed]);


In my setup, I used a Controller function as the auth endpoint and returned the expected JSON response after verifying the user is allowed to access the specified channel. The Controller function looks like this:
public function generateReverbAuth(Request $request)
    {
        // channel name will be something like private-room-231 where 231 is accountId
        $socketId = $request->input('socket_id');
        $channelName = $request->input('channel_name');

        $channelPieces = explode('-', $channelName);
        $channelAccount = end($channelPieces);

        // this verifies account id against a server known value
        if ($channelAccount != $request->attributes->get('auth_account_id')) {
            return new JsonResponse(['auth' => 'INVALID'], 403);
        }

        // this generates the required format for the response
        $stringToAuth = $socketId . ':' . $channelName;
        $hashed = hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToAuth, env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'));

        return new JsonResponse(['auth' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY') . ':' . $hashed]);
    }

Not sure what your auth looks like in Laravel, but hopefully this can point you in the right direction.

the required auth token is as follows for the authentication to work
auth : yn0yitpyoptuusssaasadsqiyjrhm:3693e882d4b886d8dadadsasdd70b4d7484e1a80247ea9cafeb4c13b2b44debc87febeef2
The string before colon : is my app key of reverb, not the secret key but app key which is this
yn0yitpyoptuusssaasadsqiyjrhm
After the colon is something that I am getting stuck at because I don't know what that is.

Yes, I had a bad copy and paste, the first value should be the app key, not the secret. The second value is a hash that is generated from the channel name and salted with the app secret.
